# C++ header file troubles

Tags: c++, header

I was tasked with making a tic tac toe game out of the .h files our groups made. I almost have it compiling, but I still get an error that says: "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "winState(char*)", referenced from:
      deki() in TicTacToe-ec883b.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"
I used deki because main was used in the .cpp file. My code is as follows:(for some reason iostream wont show up)

```
#include <iostream>

#include "boardDisplay.h"

#include "user.h"

#include "winState.h"

using namespace std;

int main()

{
}
```

and the .h file with the error is:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

char winState(char []);

int deki() {
char gameBoard[] = {'O','X','X','N','O','N','N','N','O'};
winState(gameBoard);


char winState(char gameBoard[]);
if (gameBoard[0] == gameBoard[1] && gameBoard[1] == gameBoard[2]) {
    cout << "The winner is " << gameBoard[0] << "!" << endl;
    return (gameBoard[0]);

}else if (gameBoard[3] == gameBoard[4] && gameBoard[4] == gameBoard[5]) {
    cout << "The winner is " << gameBoard[3] << "!" << endl;
    return gameBoard[3];
}else if (gameBoard[6] == gameBoard[7] && gameBoard[7] == gameBoard[8]) {
    cout << "The winner is " << gameBoard[6] << "!" << endl;
    return gameBoard[6];
}else if (gameBoard[0] == gameBoard[3] && gameBoard[3] == gameBoard[6]) {
    cout << "The winner is " << gameBoard[0] << "!" << endl;
    return gameBoard[0];
}else if (gameBoard[1] == gameBoard[4] && gameBoard[4] == gameBoard[7]) {
    cout << "The winner is " << gameBoard[1] << "!" << endl;
    return gameBoard[1];
}else if (gameBoard[2] == gameBoard[5] && gameBoard[5] == gameBoard[8]) {
    cout << "The winner is " << gameBoard[2] << "!" << endl;
    return gameBoard[2];
}else if (gameBoard[0] == gameBoard[4] && gameBoard[4] == gameBoard[8]) {
    cout << "The winner is " << gameBoard[0] << "!" << endl;
    return gameBoard[0];
}else if (gameBoard[6] == gameBoard[4] && gameBoard[4] == gameBoard[2]) {
    cout << "The winner is " << gameBoard[6] << "!" << endl;
    return gameBoard[6];
}else if ((gameBoard[0]!='1')&&(gameBoard[1]!='2')&&(gameBoard[2]!='3')&&(gameBoard[3]!='4')&&(gameBoard[4]!='5')&&(gameBoard[5]!='6')&&(gameBoard[6]!='7')&&(gameBoard[7]!='8')&&(gameBoard[8]!='9')){
    cout << "CATS GAME!" << endl;
    return 'D';
}else {
    cout << "The game is not over yet." << endl;
return 'G';
}
}
```

Comment: Generally (though possibly regardless of the problem that you've encountered), most of the stuff in your h file should be placed in a cpp file.

Comment: You don't have a definition of `winState`, just a couple of declarations and a call.

Comment: @barakmanos The conditionals are inside `deki`.

Comment: @molbdnilo: Yes, I've just noticed that. The indentation got me confused I suppose. That (repeating) declaration of function `winState` inside function `deki` most certainly got me confused. In any case, the first part of my comment remains as is though.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you've put `;` instead of `{` in `char winState(char gameBoard[]);`

So your function should look like this:

```
char winState(char gameBoard[]){
if (gameBoard[0] == gameBoard[1] && gameBoard[1] == gameBoard[2]) {
    cout << "The winner is " << gameBoard[0] << "!" << endl;
    return (gameBoard[0]);

}else if (gameBoard[3] == gameBoard[4] && gameBoard[4] == gameBoard[5]) {
    cout << "The winner is " << gameBoard[3] << "!" << endl;
    return gameBoard[3];
}else if (gameBoard[6] == gameBoard[7] && gameBoard[7] == gameBoard[8]) {
    cout << "The winner is " << gameBoard[6] << "!" << endl;
    return gameBoard[6];
}else if (gameBoard[0] == gameBoard[3] && gameBoard[3] == gameBoard[6]) {
    cout << "The winner is " << gameBoard[0] << "!" << endl;
    return gameBoard[0];
}else if (gameBoard[1] == gameBoard[4] && gameBoard[4] == gameBoard[7]) {
    cout << "The winner is " << gameBoard[1] << "!" << endl;
    return gameBoard[1];
}else if (gameBoard[2] == gameBoard[5] && gameBoard[5] == gameBoard[8]) {
    cout << "The winner is " << gameBoard[2] << "!" << endl;
    return gameBoard[2];
}else if (gameBoard[0] == gameBoard[4] && gameBoard[4] == gameBoard[8]) {
    cout << "The winner is " << gameBoard[0] << "!" << endl;
    return gameBoard[0];
}else if (gameBoard[6] == gameBoard[4] && gameBoard[4] == gameBoard[2]) {
    cout << "The winner is " << gameBoard[6] << "!" << endl;
    return gameBoard[6];
}else if ((gameBoard[0]!='1')&&(gameBoard[1]!='2')&&(gameBoard[2]!='3')&&(gameBoard[3]!='4')&&(gameBoard[4]!='5')&&(gameBoard[5]!='6')&&(gameBoard[6]!='7')&&(gameBoard[7]!='8')&&(gameBoard[8]!='9')){
    cout << "CATS GAME!" << endl;
    return 'D';
}else {
    cout << "The game is not over yet." << endl;
return 'G';
}
}
```

Also notice that you cannot define function inside another function

Comment: Also notice that none of this code should be in a header file.  Every file that includes this header file will get an error that it is duplicating the definition of winState.